# Convert string YYYY-MM-DD to date datatype and handle conversion errors

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 4 string-datatype columns in a **SQL Server 2008 SP4** table that should be dates. I cant change that so I need a way to convert those strings to dates. The string is formatted as "YYYY-MM-DD".

For 2 of those columns, a `CONVERT(datetime, [columname], 101)` works but the other 2 have strings that go like this "1700-01-01" and when I try to convert them it shows a conversion out-of-range error.

I expect all strings values to be converted to a date, if the conversion fails I rather have it as a blank or any other way, I accept recommendations when handling date conversions errors. This table will be extensively used in applications made in C#/VBA and excel queries. Specifically for Excel, I need a friendly way to show this conversion errors in queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`TRY_CONVERT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) which returns `null` if the conversion is not possible:

```
TRY_CONVERT(datetime, '1700-01-01', 101)
```

will return `null` instead of an error.
I think this works for **SQL Server 2012**+
If your version does not support it, you can check for the year part of the string and do something like this:

```
case 
  when left([columname], 4) < '1753' then null
  else CONVERT(datetime, [columname], 101)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on SQL Server version, you can try using:

```
TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, [columnname], 101)
```

Instead of failing, this will produce a `NULL` value that you can then handle gracefully.

I didn't spot you're using SQL Server 2008. You could try using `ISDATE()` function.

```sql
SELECT CASE ISDATE('1700-01-01')
        WHEN 1 THEN CONVERT(DATETIME, '1700-01-01', 101)
        ELSE NULL
    END AS Converted
```

This is probably best you can use. I'm not 100% sure if `ISDATE()` always behaves correctly, given that `ISNUMERIC()` has issues.